# Rectangle around a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout consisting of some buttons. I want to draw a rectangle around the TableLayout. I am not sure how this could be done. From my research, I found that I would need to extend a View and use the onDraw event of this view. But, the point I am confused with is "How is it possible to include the TableLayout within the View"?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

My sample code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/numkeypad"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:stretchColumns="*"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:background="@color/contents_text"
    >
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:background="#404040"
                  android:layout_span="2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Test1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Test1"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                >
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Test2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Test2"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:background="#404040"
                  android:layout_span="2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Test11"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Test11"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                >
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Test22"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Test22"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And the output I have is

[image]

And what I want is something like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend FrameLayout to draw the rectangle according to it's dimensions in the *onDraw()* method (after calling ***super***.onDraw() of course)
Say you extended class is com.example.MyFrameLayout.

Then you can declare the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.MyFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/numkeypad"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/contents_text">

        ...
    </TableLayout>
</com.example.MyFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why do I get "There is no default constructor available in android.widget.FrameLayout" when I try to extend FrameLayout in my class?

Comment: When you use the custom view in layout xml, you need to define the following constructor (for my example): MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) - just call super(context, attrs) inside and do your further initialization if needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help on the constructor. I now have everything like you said, but I never had the constructor on the new Layout ever being called. This was perhaps because this.setWillNotDraw(false) was missing from the constructor. After adding this I have a perfect shape I was looking for.